# iOS app not showing up in app-store search results after bumping required version

Tags: ios, app-store

The app has been on the iOS app store for years. In a recent update, the minimum required iOS version changed from iOS 9 to iOS 12.

What I expect the user-experience for iOS 9, 10, 11 to be: if you search for the app you should **see it** in the App Store search results. (It would be great if users could install the older version but I understand Apple doesn't allow/facilitate this? bummer)

What I see on an iOS 9 device that had *already installed the app before the minimum requirement changed*: as expected -- appears in results, cannot install from App Store search result, must go to Purchased tab and then get the prompt to install the older version.

What a user is reporting on three iOS 11 devices that have *not* had the app installed: app does not show up in search results at all.

Anyone experienced this behaviour, or know if my expected behaviour (above) is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question,

1. If the minimum iOS version is bumped up then it won't show up for older iOS versioned device, so if your min deployment target is iOS 12 then in less than iOS 12 devices the app will not show up in app store search result.
2. If the app is already installed then, it should continue working the same way as the minimum deployment is dependent on the binary file[released build]. So until the app is uninstalled it will not have any issue
3. Yes, it won't show up as minimum deployment target is iOS 12 and the device is on iOS 11.

Hope it helps.